# spectra of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, spectral-theory

Is there a book, monograph, lecture notes, etc. where the exposition of spectral theory is restricted exclusively to matrices? I would appreciate any suggestions, recommendations, etc.

Comment: So you are looking for spectral theory for finite dimensional vector spaces?

Comment: @Chiusole: yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how interesting that theory is since every finite dimensional vector space admits a Hilbert space structure, and every linear operator is bounded and compact.

However, the Jordan/Frobenius/Smith normal forms probably give the best analog to spectral theory - and the spectral theorem for (real and complex) normal matrices. All of these can be found in any introductory linear algebra text e.g. [Smith](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9780387984551).